# Java cannot find symbol when I do a Maven Build, but code works in debugger

Tags: java, aem

I am working on an AEM site and I am trying to get the page property `teaserImage` I have the follow in my Java class, but when I do a build I get a cannot find symbol error.

```
public String getTeaserImg() {
    return this.getPageManager().getPage(url).getProperties().get("teaserImage").value;
}
```

But if I put a breakpoint on this similar function

```
public Page getPage() {
    return this.getPageManager().getPage(url);
}
```

And then execute `this.getPageManager().getPage(url).getProperties().get("teaserImage").value` in an Evulate expression window it gives me the property, so I'm not sure why on build it doesnt work when it works in this scenario.

[image]

Comment: `getProperties` returns a `ValueMap`, which has the option to coerce properties to an expected type using `T get(String, Class<T>)`. I would recommend using that. The `get` you’re calling is the default `Map.get` method that returns a plain `Object` (which you could cast to a string if you’re certain that’s what it is). Also, what you see in the debugger is the internal `value` property of a string, which gets you a `char` array. This isn’t normally available, even if you cast to `String`. So, in short, use `get("teaserImage", String.class)` to get the property value as a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot find symbol error means that the compiler cannot do this. Your code appears to be referring to something that the compiler doesn't understand.

[What does a "Cannot find symbol" or "Cannot resolve symbol" error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-or-cannot-resolve-symbol-error-mean)

In your example you are trying to get a property. If you can get that when you are debugging the code, that maybe means you forgot to add that property when you are trying to build the application.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "add that property when you are trying to build". Its a page property set in AEM